# How to use the chi squared test (a biological investigation)

Tags: chi-squared-test, contingency-tables, ecology, association-measure

Imagine four habitats - A, B, C and D - set up in a choice chamber and two species of the same family, X and Y, 20 individuals of each.

In a series of experiments, we put these species into the choice chamber - first one group of 20 (of the same species), then the other group of 20 (of the other species) in order to note down their 'choices'.

Now imagine that I have the count data of the number of individuals of each species in each quadrant of the choice chamber (mean value calculated after 22 repeats) - **how do I use the chi-squared test in this scenario**?

Do I use a 4x2 table with my four habitats along the top and my observed and expected values of the two different species in the table? Or do I have to separately calculate the chi squared of both species and their associated with the four habitats? Or do I do something else? It is *necessary* for me to do some sort of significance test. Essentially, I am interested in commenting on whether species A and/or species B have (potentially different) preferences for any of the four habitats, and if they do, then explaining that preference using biological theory from the existing literature.

For a bit more detail on how the data was collected, please see below:

I first put 20 individuals of species A into the choice chamber, all at the same time, waited 5 minutes, and then counted how many individuals were in each quadrant. I then took the species out, put them into a rest chamber and put 20 individuals of species B into the chamber and repeated the process for both species 20 times. I was not able to keep track of each individual I put in. I am therefore currently assuming that the data is totally independent each time, and that there were no herding effects, scent trails, 'memory' etc between trials. Once I had my count data (observed values), I then took a mean average for each species. These were (1.000  12.455  3.727   2.818) for species for A and (9.818 2.182   2.273   5.727) for species B. I now wish to analyse these values (or maybe I have to analyse the raw data, not just the mean?). Another thing which has just clicked - will my expected values be 5 (20/4 - assuming even distribution) or would I use the (row total*column total)/(grand total) formula?

NB. The same individuals were tested over and over again (with the rest periods in between as described above).
**Please also note**: A lot of these new ideas/clarification have come from a conversation in the comments down below. In that conversation there are also suggestions from other experts who have some ideas on how I might analyse the data - if you wish, please do skim over that conversation below. However, the main points (from my end, at least) have been summarised in this question itself.

Comment: Are 20 individuals in the choice chamber at the same time? I'd suspect what each individual does depends on the other individuals. If this is so, a key assumption of chi-squared is violated.

Comment: " won't that give me the association between the habitats and the overall species type not each individual species" - your question reads as if you are interested in the former, not the latter. By the way I think most people here can imagine how a 4*2 table looks like, no need to send anybody your file. (If it's not a 4*2 table, explain better what it is instead; also with data that small, why don't you just type the table into your question?)

Comment: @Lewian - thanks. Yes the individuals are in the choice chamber at the same time. Is this a problem now?

Comment: @Lewian - I'm essentially interested in determining/commenting on whether species A and/or species B have preferences for any of the habitats, and if they have different preferences, which the raw data seems to suggest, then explaining that using biological theory.

Comment: @Rushi Imagine some kind of animal does not care about a habitat, as long as there are many others of the same species to form a herd. In your experiment, all animals of this species would sit together in one habitat,  no matter which. With another species, maybe each male wants a chamber for himself - so they disperse even though all of them would have preferred just one chamber. Whether your animals have one of these traits is a biology question. If so, the data are not i. i. d.

Comment: Because of the original asker rushing to $\chi^2$ tables it seems to be largely overlooked, that there are lots of repetitions of this experiment as stated in "(mean value after lots of repeats)". This makes things far more complicated the a $\chi^2$ test can handle Are there fresh animals in every repetition of the experiment or are these the same animals tested over and over again?

Comment: @Bernhard - I guess I will have to research the biology as to whether my species demonstrate any herding behaviour etc. and if they do then just accept that there will be some error/unreliability in my results. In terms of your second point - the same animals are tested over and over again, with rest periods in between when the other species is tested.

Comment: @Rushi: Please update your question to include the information you're providing in comments. I advise organizing it logically rather than appending a series of edits & afterthoughts. Including the raw data isn't essential, but may help to clarify any points that aren't clear in the text - if the data-set's too large to copy in, then take just a portion of it to show its structure. (By the way, I've removed some extraneous matter from your q. - if you need an answer urgently the best thing you can do is make it as concise, clear, & enticing as you can.)

Comment: (1) Did you keep track of the individual animals? (2) Is it reasonable to assume that animals aren't learning which way to go between trials, following scent trails, or something like that; so that trials are independent? (3) It's hard to understand how the mean counts you've given are calculated: if, for each species, you take the total count for a habitat over twenty repetitions and divide by twenty, then the only possible digits in the second decimal place are '0' & '5'.

Comment: Do you have to analyse these data as they are, or can you plan and run a new experiment? The current information makes me think that what goes on is too complicated for any standard test. Either far more detailed modelling is needed (and potentially not available), or an experiment that can be analysed better. Experimental design is a key aspect of statistics - statistics can't make sense of data if data are not collected so that sense can be made of them.

Comment: Regarding analysis of the data as they are, I suspect that just presenting them and commenting on the numbers as they are is the best you can do. From a statistical point of view significance testing is not mandatory.

Comment: @Lewian: "To consult the statistician after an experiment is finished is often merely to ask him to conduct a post mortem examination. He can perhaps say what the experiment died of." - R.A. Fisher. But a two-sample permutation test with each go of twenty creatures at the chamber as the experimental unit might make sense here, at least.

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica: This won't solve the dependence issue, will it?

Comment: @Lewian: There are at least three potential dependence issues: (1) between the choice of habitat by animals in the same group of 20 (herding, ...), (2) between successive trials (memory, pheromone trails, ...), (3) repeated measures on individuals. The 1st would be solved, the 2nd not, & the 3rd could be dodged by restricting *statistical* inference to the particular group of individuals from each species.

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica - thank you both for such helpful comments. I will attempt to elaborate on each of them now.

Comment: I can only tag one user so thanks was also for you @Lewian

Comment: I was not able to track individual animals. The mean was counted in the following way (with 22 repeats). Say, in quadrant 1 for species A, I counted 3/20, then 7/20, 8/20 etc. I then took a mean value of those numbers. Regarding the faults of the experiment, I agree...I suppose I could rerun a few parts of the experiment but not entirely. It depends what you had in mind. If it was just changing the method slightly by just monitoring a few extra variables as I do the experiment then fine, but otherwise it might be difficult. I do have to comment on my data using statistics to some extent. 1/2

Comment: Finally, in terms of @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica 's final idea - it didn't make sense to me wholly but I am open to drawing upon your expertise!

Comment: Can you put one animal at a time into the choice chamber? And then only use each animal once? I'm not sure about pheromone trials and stuff so can't guarantee that this would make what the animals do independent, but it is the best shot at it that I have in mind. With such data one can probably justify a $\chi^2$-test on your 4*2 table.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126505/discussion-on-question-by-rushi-how-to-use-the-chi-squared-test-a-biological-in).

Comment: @Rushi: Thank you. 22 repeats is consistent with your reported means. but you say 20 in your question: could you please correct that. Would you also please roll up your replies to questions in the comments into your question? I think there's now all the information an answerer's likely to need, but they can't be expected to trawl the comment thread for it.  I'm placing the q. on hold again until that's done, to forestall premature answers.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen: I've brought back some of the comments that pertain to clarifying plausible assumptions & aspects of the experimental design, as they're still "live".

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica - Just finished editing the question to include all our helpful information.

Comment: @Lewian - just answering you query about using 1 individual at a time. Wouldn't that mean that my expected value in each quadrant would be less than 5 because there would only be 1 individual in the chamber!?

Comment: @Rushi: This doesn't have to do with the number of individuals at the same time, but with the overall number you use.

Comment: @Lewian - thanks. Yes, I suppose I could put them in individually.

Comment: @Lewian: On the other hand, if the beasties tend to herd/swarm , or just cohabit, in nature, their behaviour in isolation might not be the most pertinent biological question.

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica: Fair enough, subject expertise is surely needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can carry out Pearson's chi-squared test for homogeneity on the two-by-four contingency table of counts aggregated over individual animals & repetitions:

|  | Habitat A | Habitat B | Habitat C | Habitat D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Species X** | 22 | 274 | 82 | 62 |
| **Species Y** | 216 | 48 | 50 | 126 |

But the assumption justifying the treatment of the test statistic as a variate from a chi-squared distribution (with three degrees of freedom) is that for each species you've got 440 independent observations from a categorical distribution. That means, as @Lewian & @Bernhard have pointed out ...

1. Each animal chooses a habitat to settle in regardless of which the other 19 choose—they don't like to either on the one hand to crowd together, or on the other to spread themselves out.
2. There aren't "carry-over" effects between repetitions—the animals don't follow (or avoid) scent trails from previous goes, or remember the way to a desirable or an undesirable habitat
3. Given that you've repeated observations of each animal: each animal of the same species has the same propensity to choose any habitat over repetitions—it's not the case, for example, that each animal *always* chooses the same habitat, & you'd have effectively just 20 observations from which to conduct inference about the species. (This issue is often dealt with by using hierarchical models; but you haven't kept track of observations at the level of individual animals.)

The extent to which it's reasonable to suppose these ideal conditions are approached in this case is a matter of biology. As an implication is that the counts across habitats within each repetition are drawn from a common multinomial distribution, bar plots & tests for homogeneity by species may give some assurance that the data are not discrepant with the independence assumption.

---

There's a more conservative test you could perform, which you might feel appropriate given the above considerations. Calculate the chi-squared statistic as before, but treat the 44 repetitions as the experimental units. Under the null hypothesis the species labels 'X' & 'Y' are exchangeable when there are no "carry-over" effects, so generate the null distribution of the test statistic from their permutations. If you then limit *statistical* inference to the collection of individual animals participating in your study, inference about the species may be a purely *biological* argument.

Comment: I'll try & get around to illustrating the homogeneity & permutation tests.